# A question about a typographical arrangement

Tags: support, on-topic-ness

Where can I ask a question about arrangement of numbered lists of axioms in a mathematical manuscript?

- tex.stackexchange.com? (i think no, because it is not specific to TeX)
- academia.stackexchange.com?
- writers.stackexchange.com?
- other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the thing that you want to know?

- If you're asking about how to actually lay things out typographically using LaTeX, then it would be appropriate for TeX.SE.
- If you're asking about typical customs in how such things are presented by scientists, then it would be appropriate for Academia.SE.

Answer (score -4):

Academia is not for domain-specific questions about academic subjects. It's for questions about academia itself.

And just because a Stack Exchange looks like it ought to be the closest fit for a question, does not mean that a question belongs there. Most questions don't belong on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: What is your criteria for determining that this is too domain-specific?  This site is happy to take some kinds of domain-specific questions.

Comment: @jakebeal this site seems happy with domain-specific stuff as long as it's at the maths/computer science/programming end of things. A legacy of the site's origin. And that makes for an unhealthily skewed culture on the site.

Comment: What criteria would you propose, then?

Comment: For this kind of questions my criterion is: if it's a question of style that does not require extensive technical answers, it's on topic; if, instead, the answer requires the discussion of technical details about the specific subject, then it's off-topic. For me, the OP's question clearly falls in the first category (you don't need math to answer), while, e.g., [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65292/displaying-mean-with-sem-or-confidence-interval#comment157461_65292) falls in the second.

Comment: Of course, the boundaries between the two categories are fuzzy and should discussed case-by-case.

Comment: @jakebeal I propose a criterion that domain-specific typography questions are off-topic

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I was hoping you'd have a somewhat more general principle describing what causes you to judge something as "too domain-specific."  Your comment just now essentially just restates your conclusion.  If you can explain your reasoning a bit further, it's possible I might come to agree with you, but without explanation that is quite unlikely.